# Serpentine algorithm

Tags: algorithm

Can you help me out with a distribution algorithm?

Here's the deal. I have Number of pens = (Number of students * Pens per student)
So, if I have 18 students and every student has 3 pens, then we have 54 pens in total.
Every pen has an order number on it like: Pen1, Pen2, Pen3. We have to evenly distribute number of pens to every student by serpentine like this:
**(Assuming 18 students)**

**if 1 pen per user:**
person 1: pen 1
person 2: pen 2
person 3: pen 3
...
person 18: pen 18

**2 units:**

person 1: pen  1 and pen  36
person 2: pen  2 and pen  35
person 3: pen  3 and pen  34
...
person 18: pen 18 and pen 19
**3 units:**

1st person: unit 1, unit 36, unit 37
2nd person: unit 2, unit 35, unit 38
3rd person: unit 3, unit 34, unit 39
...
person 18: unit 18, unit19, unit54
**4 units per student:**

person 1: unit 1, unit 36, unit 37, and unit 72
person 2: unit 2, unit 35, unit 38, and unit 71
person 3: unit 3, unit 34, unit 39, and unit 70
...
person 18: unit18, unit19,unit 54, unit 55

So, input is Number of students + pens per student. And I need to output a distribution (array)

Comment: This sounds a lot like homework to me.  What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I do not see the logic here. Cannot even understand how I have to distribute if I have 5 units. It is not a homework.

Comment: considering I find nothing on the "Serpentine algorithm" I also say it's homework.

Comment: The logic is quite simple: person X will get pens X, PERSONS*2-(X-1), PERSONS*2 + X, PERSONS*4-(x-1), PERSONS*4+x, PERSONS*6-(x-1), PERSONS*6+x, etc. In other words, the sequence is PERSONS*N+X, PERSONS*N-(X-1), where N starts at 0 and goes up by 2 for each iteration, and X goes from 1 up to the number of PERSONS. Just pick the number of pens for each and stop appropriately. However, if this isn't homework, what exactly is it? What kind of program requires this particular functionality?

Comment: In any case, **you haven't asked a question**. You have just dumped a problem description, you haven't told us where you're stumped. Was the algorithm part it?

Comment: As for reference, this is probably the [Serpentine System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serpentine_system)

Comment: I'm not really sure why I got downvotes on the question. it looks like a nice, clear question. Anyways. Thanks: Lasse Karlsen and mjv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [Serpentine System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serpentine_system).

The following table will tell you which pens to give to each person:

```
person        Pen 1          Pen 2             Pen 3         Pen 4
  1       PERSONS*0+1    PERSONS*2-0       PERSONS*2+1   PERSONS*4-0
  2       PERSONS*0+2    PERSONS*2-1       PERSONS*2+2   PERSONS*4-1
  3       PERSONS*0+3    PERSONS*2-2       PERSONS*2+3   PERSONS*4-2
  4       PERSONS*0+4    PERSONS*2-3       PERSONS*2+4   PERSONS*4-3
  :
  :
  N       PERSONS*0+N    PERSONS*2-(N-1)   PERSONS*2+N   PERSONS*4-(N-1)
                  ^              ^                 ^             ^
                  |              |                 |             |
                  +--- start at 0 and increase 2 every 2 pens ---+---> 4, 6, 6, 8
```

And so on in both directions.

Answer (score 2):

This Python snippet below should do the trick, for all positive values of nbPersons and nbItems (ex. to distribute 7 items each to 23 people, etc.).

In a nutshell the idea is to **fill the table by row**, producing the item number given in each cell **as a function of the row and column number**
In the snippet, the `person` variable is the [1-based] row number and the `item` variable is the [again 1 based] column number.
The main trick is to assign the itemNo as a sum: that of the number of items in the preceding completed columns (`(item - 1) * nbPersons` below), plus a value for item no within the current column.  The value for current column depends if the column is even or odd, as we have to "count down" for even columns.
in the code, the forumulas are purposely "spelled out" for readability; they could be factorized instead.

```
  nbPersons = 18  // change these, or turn them into
  nbItemsPP = 5   // a function's arguments
  for person in range(1, nbPersons + 1):
    print "Person ", person
    for item in range (1, nbItemsPP + 1):
          if item % 2 == 1:    // odd column ?
              unitNo = (item - 1) * nbPersons + person
          else:                // even column ?
              unitNo = (item - 1) * nbPersons + nbPersons - person + 1
          print " U# ", unitNo,
    print
```

Results:

```
Person  1  U# 1  U# 36  U# 37  U# 72  U# 73
Person  2  U# 2  U# 35  U# 38  U# 71  U# 74
Person  3  U# 3  U# 34  U# 39  U# 70  U# 75
Person  4  U# 4  U# 33  U# 40  U# 69  U# 76
Person  5  U# 5  U# 32  U# 41  U# 68  U# 77
Person  6  U# 6  U# 31  U# 42  U# 67  U# 78
Person  7  U# 7  U# 30  U# 43  U# 66  U# 79
Person  8  U# 8  U# 29  U# 44  U# 65  U# 80
Person  9  U# 9  U# 28  U# 45  U# 64  U# 81
Person  10  U# 10  U# 27  U# 46  U# 63  U# 82
Person  11  U# 11  U# 26  U# 47  U# 62  U# 83
Person  12  U# 12  U# 25  U# 48  U# 61  U# 84
Person  13  U# 13  U# 24  U# 49  U# 60  U# 85
Person  14  U# 14  U# 23  U# 50  U# 59  U# 86
Person  15  U# 15  U# 22  U# 51  U# 58  U# 87
Person  16  U# 16  U# 21  U# 52  U# 57  U# 88
Person  17  U# 17  U# 20  U# 53  U# 56  U# 89
Person  18  U# 18  U# 19  U# 54  U# 55  U# 90
```

Comment: You code helped a lot, but I can accept only one answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's a pattern...

**5 units per student:**

```
person 1:  unit 1, unit 36, unit 37, unit 72, unit 73
person 2:  unit 2, unit 35, unit 38, unit 71, unit 74
person 3:  unit 3, unit 34, unit 39, unit 70, unit 75
...
person 18: unit18, unit 19, unit 54, unit 55, unit 90
```

etc..

It's the same as 4 units per person with one more column added on each column alternates between counting up and down.